# How to create a Partition on basis of Extents

Tags: partition, lvm

I have one question bugging me can't get rid of it. Let's assume we have to create LVM the VG will have physical extent size of 16M and LV within it will have 80 Extents.

How much space would i should assign from fdisk,gdisk or cfdisk .

I thought of this simple math (16*80) but is it right ?

Comment: See: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lv_overview  To decide what it exactly is, show some details about `pvdisplay ; vgdisplay ; lvdisplay`. The article explains well though

Comment: I've answered the question but now I realize there's something unclear to me. Can you please clarify what you mean by "How much space would i should assign from fdisk,gdisk or cfdisk"?

Comment: as we are aware that first we always create partition from fdisk,gdisk or new utility cfdisk . then comes LVM or standard partition. So my question was how to guess how much space i assign from fdisk or any other utility.

Comment: @OmiPenguin You can create a partition and use the whole size. It automatically assigns the remaining disk space to the partition. You then select 8e(lvm) type and using lvm you can `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/your_logical_volume`.  Once again see the link I posted above.

Comment: there's always overhead. LVM stores configuration and allocation metadata too. so you'll need to create a size that is strictly > 16*80 anyway. val0x00ff 's link has some information about it. here's a link having ondisk format documentation: https://github.com/libyal/libvslvm/blob/master/documentation/Logical%20Volume%20Manager%20(LVM)%20format.asciidoc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.  But normally you do the opposite: you need to create a partition of a certain size, let's say 640 Mb, so assuming the PE size of the VG is 16Mb, you create a LV of 40 extents.

> Let's assume we have to create LVM the VG will have physical extent size of 16M and LV within it will have 80 Extents.

You find this kind of request in exercises and Linux certification tests. In the real world, most of the time you don't even worry about the PE size, and specify directly the LV size in Mb/Gb.